# Is there a definition of "measure on a measureable space" that's similar in spirit to the usual definition of "distribution on a smooth manifold"?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Distributions have a remarkably simple definition: given a paracompact smooth manifold $M$, a distribution on $M$ is a linear transformation $\mathcal{C}^\infty_{\mathrm{cs}}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ where $\mathcal{C}^\infty_{\mathrm{cs}}(M)$ is the set of compactly-supported smooth functions $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

> **Question.** Can measures on a measureable space be defined in a similar way?
>
> Something like this: let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ denote a measureable space. Then a *measure* on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is an $[0,\infty]$-linear function $F(X,\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that [whatever], where $F(X,\mathcal{A})$ for the set of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions $X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$.

I was thinking that maybe the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) is the correct [whatever]. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for, but the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) is very similar in spirit.

Comment: Isn't that basically the normal definition of a measure? The usual definition is in terms of set-functions, but you can easily translate that to using simple functions. Now if you can show that definitions using the full set of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions is not more restrictive than that of the simple functions, you are done.

Comment: On the other hand, linearity usually mean finite linear combination. So a subtlety could be whether there is a difference between allowing finite linear combinations of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions versus allowing countable linear combinations of simple functions.

Comment: [These notes](http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/realweb/real.pdf) by W. G. Faris define the integral in the way you suggested; see sections 7.6 and 8.1.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F., thanks!